# React-site to pdf with images and graphs

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation, single-page-application, jspdf, html2canvas

Could you suggest a library which is free and effective in converting reactjs SPA into pdf. I need following two constraints:

1. There should not be random page breaks inside the application like in middle of image or graphs
2. We need to ensure that each page of pdf is containing constant header and footer

I am currently using html2canvas and jspdf but not able to find any way to implement these two. Could anyone help me with this.

This is the piece of code that I am using currently:

downloadCurrentPage: function (rootElement, fileName, callback, applyScale = false) {
try {

```
        let renderFooter = function (doc, pageNo, pageWidth, pageHeight) {
            try {
                let str = "Page " + pageNo;
                doc.page = pageNo;
                doc.setTextColor(40);
                doc.setFontSize(8);
                doc.text(str, pageWidth - 90, pageHeight - 40);
            } catch (ex) {
            }
        }
        
        /**sclae 2 is used to remove Grey boxes coming because of box-shadowing */
        const scale = applyScale ? {scale: 2} : {};
        
        let inputDiv = document.getElementById(rootElement);
        html2canvas(inputDiv, scale)
            .then((canvas) => {
                try {
                    
                    let definedWidth = 592.28;
                    let definedHeight = 841.89;
                    
                    let contentWidth = canvas.width;
                    let contentHeight = canvas.height;
                    let pageHeight = contentWidth / definedWidth * definedHeight;
                    let leftHeight = contentHeight;
                    let position = 0;
                    let imgWidth = 595.28;
                    let imgHeight = 592.28 / contentWidth * contentHeight;
                    
                    let pageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
                    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
                    let pageCount = 1;
                    
                    
                    pdf.setPage(pageCount)
                    if (leftHeight < pageHeight) {
                        pdf.addImage(pageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                    } else {
                        while (leftHeight > 0) {
                            pdf.addImage(pageData, 'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
                            leftHeight -= pageHeight;
                            position -= definedHeight;
                            renderFooter(pdf, pageCount, definedWidth, definedHeight);
                            if (leftHeight > 0) {
                                pdf.addPage();
                                pageCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    pdf.save(fileName);
                    
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(true);
                    }
                    
                } catch (ex) {
                    console.error(ex);
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(false);
                    }
                }
            })
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error("AppUtils : downloadCurrentPage : ERROR : ", ex);
        if (callback) {
            callback(false);
        }
    }
}
```

===============

I need to add defined footer and header on each page
the graphs or image should not break in case of page breaks

Kindly let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can anyone help here with any html2canvas and jspdf itsel, then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [React PDF](https://react-pdf.org/)**

using npm : `npm install @react-pdf/renderer --save`

Comment: Is it possible to avoid random page breaks instance inside this library?

Comment: Yes but you need to setup pages using HTML